# Mail's preview image got cut when using MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: ios

I have an APP to share people's photos to Mail, but on iPhone 6 Plus, I found it's preview image sometimes got cut, like this :

Image link is here:

[Broken Image](http://cl.ly/image/2i0i3H413Z0j/Screen%20Shot%202015-04-09%20at%20%E4%B8%8A%E5%8D%8811.29.27.png)

In fact, there is a string like "Send from my phone" after image, it is cut too.

But if I move cursor to the end of the image, and press return on the keyboard, the image and "Send from my phone" become intactness.

I'm sorry, I can't send image directly,

here are the links:

[Move Cursor](http://cl.ly/image/1o0v2X463W2t/Screen%20Shot%202015-04-09%20at%20%E4%B8%8A%E5%8D%8811.47.36.png)

Here is my code:

```
- (void) shareToMailWithALAsset:(ALAsset *) asset {
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
      NSString *imageName = asset.defaultRepresentation.filename;
      MFMailComposeViewController *mailVC = [MFMailComposeViewController new];
      mailVC.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [mailVC setMessageBody:"test"
                    isHTML:NO];
      UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:asset.defaultRepresentation.fullScreenImage];
        NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1);
      [mailVC addAttachmentData: data
                     mimeType:@"image/jpeg"
                     fileName:imageName];
      [self presentViewController:mailVC
                       animated:YES
                     completion:nil];
    }
    else {
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciate. Thanks.

Comment: another image link:  [Press Return](http://cl.ly/image/1z2t3j3t0q1x/Screen%20Shot%202015-04-09%20at%20%E4%B8%8A%E5%8D%8811.48.27.png)

Comment: i have exactly the same problem... sometimes i will displayed correctly but often it doesn't. have you found out something yet?

Comment: @donmarkusi,  no, haven't got any useful information.